How do I hide the controls before the video is being played in Mediaelement.js?
I want to hide the controls bar at the bottom before the video is being played. How can i do that?
I was expecting to have the controls bar hidden before the video plays.
I tried googling and using Ai such as chatgpt and gemini.
